# Connecting Spring Cloud Config Server with my git local repository

Tags: git, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I am trying to connect my Spring Cloud Config Server to my local git repository. Is there any problem if there are have spaces in between my local git repo path?

In application.properties file of my spring cloud config server project, I am setting the local git repo path in the below way:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///media/mohit/48D65875D658656A/1.STUDY/UDEMY/Master Microservices with SpringBoot & SpringCloud/workspace_microservices/git-localconfig-repo
```

While accessing `localhost:8888/limits-service/default`, I am getting an error

> This site can’t be reached, localhost refused to connect

Comment: Did you test your mentioned path?

Comment: Yes I have tested. While accessing http://localhost:8888/limits-service/default , I am getting an error as : "This site can’t be reached, localhost refused to connect" . Here 'limits-service.properties' is the property file present inside my spring cloud config project and also saved to my local git repo

Comment: Do you have any `.git` folder in your git folder( your path)?

Comment: You do not need `limits-service.properties` in the spring cloud project. Just save it in the local git repo.

Comment: yes i have .git folder in my local git repo

Comment: Because it is `git` repo. Go to your local git repo and creat it. Open terminal and run `git init` then `git add --all` then `git commit -m "your message"`. Repeat this commands when you change each file in your local git repo.

Comment: i m sorry but the .git folder was hidden. So its already present there

Comment: I put a sample code here: https://github.com/Nasir-S/spring-cloud-config-server set spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri in the application.properties file.

Comment: As u can see in the question that i have already set the local git repo path in spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri , but i wanted to know if there are spaces in the path of local git repo then will there be any problem